# How to create a new user in the /home directory

Tags: kali-linux

I'm trying to create a new user in the /home directory but I keep getting errors saying /home doesn't exist.

Comment: `man mkdir` may be helpful.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show **how** you are trying to create the user, and the *complete, verbatim* error message

Comment: Sounds like you'd be better using a user-friendly distribution rather than one designed for experienced security professionals. Try Mint, Ubuntu, or maybe Fedora for an easy starting point

Comment: If it says that /home doesn't exist, I would believe it. You may have to create /home. I do agree with @roaima that a problem like this should not be an obstacle if you had a minimum of Linux skills. Without a minimum of Linux skills, don't use Kali.

Comment: You don't create users in /home... you create directories in /home.  Users go in the passwd and shadow files.  Having said that, you could try "mkdir -p /home/username"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem of an optional directory not existing will be solved immediately by the creation of that directory